# Core Bluetooth - Unable to Write Value using CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am designing an iOS app with a custom made bluetooth enabled device that sends and receives text from my iPhone. I am able to send text data to the device when I send a CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse, but that using that sends data as best-effort and not guaranteed according to Apple documentation. When I try writing data using .WithResponse, I get an unknown error, so I downloaded the BT Server Log on my iPhone, and saw the following message:

> writeCharacteristic - Notice  -   ATT   -     Writing value with response to characteristic handle 0x0025 on device "(#my device number#)"
>
> runCommand    -       Error  -    ATT   -     Characteristic handle 0x0024 is not writeable!
>
> processCommands  -    Error  -    ATT    -    Command failed for device "(#my device number#)"

Would this be an issue with the bluetooth chip? Or am I doing something wrong? Any input is greatly appreciated! If any extra code is required, let me know and I'll put it up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to examine the `properties` of your `CBCharacteristic` on your `CBService` - If `CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite` is specified then the characteristic supports write with a response.  If only `CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse` is specified then you can't execute a write with response.

To change this you will need to modify the firmware in your BLE device.